# Copy cells from multiple columns into respective rows to another column

Tags: excel, vba

So I have three columns (H, I, J) with data that do not overlap. I want to copy these values into one column R. I made a table below with an example

[image: Table here]

I have this code below which splits text in each column by delimiter and creates a new copied row from that with the split values, and then the b variable represents the R column which copies the delimited text to this column. The problem with this code is that when there is nothing to be split in a cell, then nothing is copied over to the R column.

```
Sub SplitString()

    Dim Genres As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim b As Range
    Dim FirstCellRef As String

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("H1", ActiveSheet.Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Find( _
        What:="; ", _
        LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        FirstCellRef = r.Address
        Do
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            Set b = r.Offset(0, 10)
            Genres = Split(r.Value, "; ")
            r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(Genres)).EntireRow.Insert
            For i = 0 To UBound(Genres)
                r.Offset(i, 0).Value = Genres(i)
                b.Offset(i, 0).Value = Genres(i)
            Next i
            Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("H1", ActiveSheet.Range("H1").End(xlDown)).FindNext(r)
        Loop While Not r Is Nothing 'And r.Address <> FirstCellRef
    End If

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("I1", ActiveSheet.Range("I1").End(xlDown)).Find( _
        What:="; ", _
        LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        FirstCellRef = r.Address
        Do
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            Set b = r.Offset(0, 9)
            Genres = Split(r.Value, "; ")
            r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(Genres)).EntireRow.Insert
            For i = 0 To UBound(Genres)
                r.Offset(i, 0).Value = Genres(i)
                b.Offset(i, 0).Value = Genres(i)
            Next i
            Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("I1", ActiveSheet.Range("I1").End(xlDown)).FindNext(r)
        Loop While Not r Is Nothing 'And r.Address <> FirstCellRef
    End If

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("J1", ActiveSheet.Range("J1").End(xlDown)).Find( _
        What:="; ", _
        LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        FirstCellRef = r.Address
        Do
            r.EntireRow.Copy
            Set b = r.Offset(0, 8)
            Genres = Split(r.Value, "; ")
            r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(Genres)).EntireRow.Insert
            For i = 0 To UBound(Genres)
                r.Offset(i, 0).Value = Genres(i)
                b.Offset(i, 0).Value = Genres(i)
            Next i
            Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("J1", ActiveSheet.Range("J1").End(xlDown)).FindNext(r)
        Loop While Not r Is Nothing 'And r.Address <> FirstCellRef
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Either modifying this existing code, or a new code that just does what I showed in the table would be fine for me. Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the semicolon all about? It's nowhere to be found in your screenshot. Do the results have to be written into several columns if a semicolon is found e.g. `A;  B; C` to columns `R:T`? Please, elaborate. If `If Not r Is Nothing Then` is true, then `Loop While Not r Is Nothing` will always be true, so you have an endless loop. `r.Address <> FirstCellRef` is the important part.

Comment: In your example, your `R` column can be created with a simple worksheet formula.  Why bother with VBA?  On the other hand, if your example is not representative of your real data, why post it?

Comment: @VBasic2008 The semicolumn is the delimiter. This code is a previous step which splits text into their respective columns if the cell contains a delimiter. This step already works so it is not relevant to the problem I stated. The reason I included this code is because I tried to do the copying the cells into column R in this but it does not work as intended. Thank you for the advice on the second part.

Comment: The purpose was to encourage to post your real problem. I didn't understand your reference to a "delimiter" where none is shown in your data, which I assumed to be that in columns `H, I and J`.  From that I assumed that your actual data is more complicated than what you showed, so I didn't feel like wasting my time. Possibly you are showing an intermediate step in those columns, rather than the initial data. But having wasted this much time, though, simply `R1: =LOOKUP(2,1/LEN(H1:J1),H1:J1)` will return, in column R, the entry in column H, I or J as you show in your table.

Answer (score 0):

When adding rows it is simpler to work from the bottom upwards.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SplitString2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ar(2), n As Long, c As Long, s As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, i As Long, count As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.count - 1
        For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            n = 0
            ' scan cols H to J
            For c = 8 To 10
                s = Trim(.Cells(r, c)) '
                ' remove trailing ;
                If Right(s, 1) = ";" Then
                    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
                End If

                ' determine how many rows required in total
                If Len(s) > 0 Then
                    ' split
                    ar(c - 8) = Split(s, ";")
                    n = n + UBound(ar(c - 8)) + 1 ' summate
                Else
                    ar(c - 8) = Array()
                End If
            Next

            ' insert n-1 rows if n > 1
            If n > 1 Then
                ws.Rows(r).Copy
                ws.Rows(r).Resize(n - 1).Insert
                ws.Range("H" & r).Resize(n, 3).Value2 = "" ' clear cols H:J
                count = count + n - 1

                ' fill in cols H:J and R
                n = 0
                For c = 8 To 10
                    For i = 0 To UBound(ar(c - 8))
                        s = Trim(ar(c - 8)(i))
                        ws.Cells(r + n, c) = s
                        ws.Cells(r + n, "R") = s
                        n = n + 1
                    Next
                Next
            Else
                ' existing row copy H or I or J to R
                For c = 8 To 10
                   If Len(ws.Cells(r, c)) > 0 Then
                       ws.Cells(r, "R") = Trim(ws.Cells(r, c))
                   End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
 
    MsgBox count & " rows inserted."
End Sub
```